# Rspec + shared_examples, how to avoid repeated object creation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have a following code snipped in my Rspec.

I would like to create a supplier just once but instead, I am seeing a different supplier object being created for each test, (a total of 3 times). I verified this via binding.pry in the actual implementation.

1. Can someone explain why this is happening?
2. How to avoid this?

I can not use build instead of create as I need id associated with the supplier in my implementation.

I am using shared examples as I have more than 50 products to write the same tests for.

```
let!(:supplier) { create(:supplier) }

shared_examples 'a product not in stock with supplier' do |product|
  it 'raises an error' do
    expect { described_class.dispatch_product!(supplier, product) }.to raise_error 'Product is not in stock'
  end
end

context 'when the state is not supported' do
  it_behaves_like 'a product not in stock with supplier', Chair_1
  it_behaves_like 'a product not in stock with supplier', Table_1
  it_behaves_like 'a product not in stock with supplier', Sofa_1
end
```

Comment: Why do you need to verify this behavior for 50 different products in the first place? I would expect the implementation to be the same, and therefore it should be enough to test it once for one product.

Comment: That''s a fair question but I am more curious to learn how to avoid the repeated creation of supplier objects.

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behavior when using `let` or `let!`. Its value will be memorized for one expectation (one `it` block).

When you want to avoid re-creating the `supplier` for each test, then I see two options:

1. Combine all expectations into one

   ```
   let(:supplier) { create(:supplier) }

   shared_examples 'a product not in stock with supplier' do |products|
     it 'raises an error' do
       products.each do |product|
         expect { 
           described_class.dispatch_product!(supplier, product) 
         }.to raise_error 'Product is not in stock'
       end
     end
   end

   context 'when the state is not supported' do
     it_behaves_like 'a product not in stock with supplier', 
                     [Chair_1, Table_1, Sofa_1]
   end
   ```
2. Or store the supplier in an instance variable and pass it to the shared examples manually

   ```
   shared_examples 'a product not in stock with supplier' do |product|
     it 'raises an error' do
       expect { 
         described_class.dispatch_product!(supplier, product) 
       }.to raise_error 'Product is not in stock'
     end
   end

   context 'when the state is not supported' do
     before(:context) { @supplier ||= create(:supplier) }

     it_behaves_like 'a product not in stock with supplier', 
                     Chair_1 { let(:supplier) { @supplier } }
     it_behaves_like 'a product not in stock with supplier', 
                     Table_1 { let(:supplier) { @supplier } }
     it_behaves_like 'a product not in stock with supplier', 
                     Sofa_1 { let(:supplier) { @supplier } }
   end
   ```

I don't like any of those options, and think they make the specs harder to read and are ugly workarounds RSpec's default behavior and design principles.

What you might want to consider for such cases are using [Fixtures](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FixtureSet.html) in your tests in addition to factories. If you created just one default fixture for a supplier, then you could reuse the same supplier for all kind of test in which you do not care about using a supplier with any specific configuration.

If you had fixtures configured in your app and had a valid `suppliers(:default)` fixture, then it could look like this:

```
let(:supplier) { suppliers(:default) } # would reuse the same instance from the db

shared_examples 'a product not in stock with supplier' do |product|
  it 'raises an error' do
    expect { 
      described_class.dispatch_product!(supplier, product) 
    }.to raise_error 'Product is not in stock'
  end
end

context 'when the state is not supported' do
  it_behaves_like 'a product not in stock with supplier', Chair_1
  it_behaves_like 'a product not in stock with supplier', Table_1
  it_behaves_like 'a product not in stock with supplier', Sofa_1
end
```